# До какой версии PHPMyAdmin работает без ajax? и показывает выполненые запросы при создании таблицы

Tags: phpmyadmin, php

Новые версии очень бесят

Куда дели чтоб показывало какой именно запрос выполнился

До какой версии этих новых наворотов не было?

и где можно скачать старую нормальную версию админа чтоб в денвер пихнуть

Answer (score 3):

[Ajax можно легко выключить так](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Config) или [так](http://www.netvivs.com/how-to-disable-ajax-popup-in-recent-versions-of-phpmyadmin/)

> `$cfg['AjaxEnable'] = false;`

Попробуйте версии от [3.3.x и старше](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmyadmin/files/phpMyAdmin/3.3.10.5/).

Comment: Спасибо

3.3.10.5

это она и есть, то что нужно

Comment: в конфиги с ходу не нашел параметра AjaxEnable

а времени разбираться нет